# Is there a way in direct3D 9 for scaling a sprite by the nearest neighbor?

Tags: c++, directx, textures, sprite, direct3d

I know that, there is a way to set "the nearest neighbor" for 3D render. I mean:

```
d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

But it doesn't work for sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Begin` to start rendering your sprite, you need to pass the flag `D3DXSPRITE_DONOTMODIFY_RENDERSTATE` or it will use the states documented [in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In this case, you need to set all of the state you require beforehand, and make sure you select the desired sampler state.